# add link in legend text in fusion chart

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, fusioncharts

How can I add link in legend text in fusion chart?

I tried below code but it is adding link in chart not on legend's text:

```
"data": [{
        "label": "Workplace Services",
        "value": "24",
        "color": "#81cee3",
        "link": "http://google.com" // added this
      }]
```

[image: add-link]

Answer (score 2):

For adding a link to the legend you need to use FusionCharts legendItemClicked API event, to know more check this link  - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events#legenditemclicked-97

Refer this snippet -   "events": {

```
  "legendItemClicked": function(eventObj, dataObj) {

    if( eventObj.data.datasetName==="Food"){
   window.location.href= "https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/";
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the legendItemClicked API event, to know more check this link - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/api/fusioncharts/fusioncharts-events#legenditemclicked-97

```
 FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'pie2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '550',
    height: '350',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Split of revenue by product categories",
        "subCaption": "Last year",
        "numberPrefix": "$",
        "showPercentInTooltip": "0",
        "decimals": "1",
        "legendPosition": "right",
        //Theme
        "theme": "fusion",
        "tooltipBorderRadius": "20"
      },
      "data": [{
          "label": "Food",
          "value": "285040"
        },
        {
          "label": "Apparels",
          "value": "146330"
        },
        {
          "label": "Electronics",
          "value": "105070"
        },
        {
          "label": "Household",
          "value": "49100"
        }
      ]
    },
    "events": {

      "legendItemClicked": function(eventObj, dataObj) {
        if (eventObj.data.datasetName === "Food") {
          window.location.href = "https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/";
        }
      }
    }

  }).render();

});
```

Check here demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/7urtdL65/